# How to open and manipulate a XML file with a windows store app (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, xml, windows-8

I'm trying to use a xml file to store user customization for my metro style aplication. I'd like to know how can I load the file, get certain elements within the file and write new ones.

I'm using javascript.

Comment: did you read the maunal?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try{
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e){
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Open the xml (instead of a remote url , use the local path)

```
  function openXML(){
       xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", item.url,true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    };
```

Finally work on the tags

```
   function stateChanged() {
      if(xmlHttp[item.key] != null )
            if (xmlHttp[item.key].readyState == 4 ) {
                var xmlHeader = xmlHttp[.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("TAG");
            }
    }
```